# Count the number of /etc/passwd entries that have no password?

Tags: scripts, users, passwd

How can I count the number of `/etc/password` entries that have no password?

Answer (score 3):

I *think* that to find entries with no password set, you will have to use `/etc/shadow`:

```
sudo grep -Ec '\!|\*' /etc/shadow
```

The `!` and `*` characters indicate that there is no Unix password for the user, for example:

```
root:!:17092:0:99999:7:::
colord:*:17086:0:99999:7:::
```

The entries in `/etc/shadow` correspond to those in `/etc/passwd`

Instead of a count, you could get a clean list of just the usernames:

```
sudo grep -E '\!|\*' /etc/shadow | grep -o '^[^:]*'
```

You can use `-v` to invert the match and count or list users **with** passwords of course:

```
sudo grep -vE '\!|\*' /etc/shadow | grep -o '^[^:]*'
```

---

Notes:

- `-E` use ERE so we can use `|` for alternation
- `-c` return a count of the lines, not the lines themselves
- `-o` just print the matched part
- `'^[^:]*'` from the start of the line to the first `:`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $(($(cat /etc/passwd | egrep "^*:x" | wc | awk '{print $1}')-$(cat /etc/passwd | wc | awk '{print $1}')))
```

This just counts the entries which don't have a password at all